# Bootstrap: move descriptions from column titles to row names on mobile

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a table more mobile-responsive, and running into an issue with columns titles.

Right now, the column titles on desktop are 'Display Color,' 'Up' and 'Down.' Ideally, when it switches to mobile, 'up' and 'down' would move to the rows so that instead of the rows saying "A:" for example, it would say "A: Up" and then the next row would be "A: Down" or something like that. Is there a built-in way to do something like this in bootstrap?

[here](https://jsbin.com/jumakaleti/edit?html,output) is a jsbin- you can see what I mean by adjusting the width. Currently, when you adjust to mobile-sized (aka smaller) it's not clear which of the dropdowns is for 'Up' and which is for 'Down'

Here's the code:

```
<!-- views/profile.ejs -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/main.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<style>
        body        { padding-top:80px; word-wrap:break-word; }
    </style>
<script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/scripts.js" />
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
        <strong>Display Color</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
        <strong>Up</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
        <strong>Down</strong>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
          <strong>A:</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
          <select class="bootstrap-select btn col-md-12" name="color1U" autocomplete="off">

            <option name="name0" value="0" 
             >white<span class="colorRectangle"></span>
            </option>

            <option name="name1" value="1" 
             >red<span class="colorRectangle"></span>
            </option>

            <option name="name2" value="2" 
             >orange<span class="colorRectangle"></span>
            </option>


          </select>
        </div>          
        <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
          <select class="bootstrap-select btn  col-md-12" name="color1D" autocomplete="off">

            <option name="name0" value="0" 
            >white</option>

            <option name="name1" value="1" 
            >red</option>

            <option name="name2" value="2" 
            >orange</option>

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>       

      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
          <strong>B: </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
          <select class="bootstrap-select btn col-md-12" name="color2U" autocomplete="off">

            <option name="name0" value="0" 
             >white<span class="colorRectangle"></span>
            </option>

            <option name="name1" value="1" 
            selected="selected" >red<span class="colorRectangle"></span>
            </option>

            <option name="name2" value="2" 
             >orange<span class="colorRectangle"></span>
            </option>

            <option name="name3" value="3" 
             >yellow<span class="colorRectangle"></span>
            </option>

          </select>
        </div>          
        <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
          <select class="bootstrap-select btn  col-md-12" name="color2D" autocomplete="off">

            <option name="name0" value="0" 
            >white</option>

            <option name="name1" value="1" 

              selected="selected">red</option>

            <option name="name2" value="2" 
            >orange</option>

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>       

    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle, and let me know if you want this or not?

```
<h1>
  Resize Window
</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-th="Sr. No.">1</td>
      <td data-th="Company">quality designs</td>
      <td data-th="Name">Eugene silinda</td>
      <td data-th="Country">South Africa</td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wLdvcs06/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
    <h4>Display Color</h4>
    <p>A:</p>
    <p>B:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
    <h4>Up</h4>
    <select class="bootstrap-select btn col-md-12" name="color1U" autocomplete="off">
        <option name="name0" value="0">white<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
        <option name="name1" value="1">red<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
        <option name="name2" value="2">orange<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
    </select>
    <select class="bootstrap-select btn col-md-12" name="color1U" autocomplete="off">
        <option name="name0" value="0">white<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
        <option name="name1" value="1">red<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
        <option name="name2" value="2">orange<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
    <h4>Down</h4>
    <select class="bootstrap-select btn col-md-12" name="color1U" autocomplete="off">
        <option name="name0" value="0">white<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
        <option name="name1" value="1">red<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
        <option name="name2" value="2">orange<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
    </select>
    <select class="bootstrap-select btn col-md-12" name="color1U" autocomplete="off">
        <option name="name0" value="0">white<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
        <option name="name1" value="1">red<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
        <option name="name2" value="2">orange<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```